# How to remove warning 'The 'configuration' element is not declared.' Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, warnings

(c#) The error `'The 'configuration' element is not declared.'` comes up on my program. It shows it on line 2, which is `using System.Collections.Generic;`. The program compiles fine, and runs fine But the warning is there, and if its a problem, I want to know what it means. If it is a problem with my code, tell me what it would be (eg. variable declaration), and I can post some code. But my program is ~200 lines, so I would rather not post it here. Is this error coming up because of an error I made? or is it a bug? or is it easily fixable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED 
Visual Studio just needed to be restarted.

Answer (score -1):

It means your `app.config` or `web.config` file (depending on what kind of program you're writing) doesn't have a `<configuration></configuration>` element.

Put the following into your `app.config` or `web.config` file:

```
<configuration xmlns="schemaURL">
   <!-- Your settings here -->
</configuration>
```

Comment: That was there, except for xmlns="schemaURL", and after adding that, the warning was gone. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I spoke too soon. After adding that, the compiler failed to run, saying the config was improperly configured. This question is still open