# Application configuration is invalid - application won't start

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I had configuration warning in app.config of my wpf application.

my entire app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns="schema URL">
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

I tried :

[How to remove warning 'The 'configuration' element is not declared.' Visual Studio C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919393/how-to-remove-warning-the-configuration-element-is-not-declared-visual-stud)

and

[The configuration element is not declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12523996/the-configuration-element-is-not-declared)

and as stated in one of answers, tried to restart VS and start again. No luck

[image]

The configuration warning is gone, however the application can't start

Comment: I believe the problem might be `xmlns="schema URL"` in your `<configuration>` tag. "schema URL" seems to me to be invalid.

Comment: delete xmlns="shema URL" <configuration> and try rebuild your program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this `App.config` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <startup> 
            <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
        </startup>
    </configuration>
```